# Firefox doesn't respect font-size in SVG text

Tags: css, firefox, svg

I am running into an issue where Firefox doesn't seem to apply the `font-size` property (set in CSS) to SVG `text` elements.

The example below is enough to reproduce the issue on Firefox:

```html
    <svg width="40em" height="25em" viewBox="0 0 40 25">
        <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
            text { font-size: 1px; }
            text.foo { font-size: 2px; }
        ]]></style>
        <text x="0" y="10" class="foo">Hello, world! foo</text>
        <text x="0" y="20">Hello, world! bar</text>
    </svg>
```

Here is the expected result (Chromium): [image]

Here is what Firefox renders: [image]

I can't find what I am doing wrong. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: can't repro FF 38.0  and 40.0 on MacOs

Comment: Can you render text in 1px font-size with the same font on html elements with your os?

Comment: Have you set a minimum font size in Firefox preferences?

Comment: @RobertLongson: that was it. Please answer so I can accept you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You likely have a minimum font size set.  This is a known bug, hopefully we'll fix it someday.

Unset it like this.

[image: Minimum font size]